# What do you call monoidal categories where you can only delete on the left?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Cartesian monoidal categories come with projection morphisms that let you go from $A \otimes B$ to $A$ or from $A \otimes B$ to $B.$

I am wondering if there are kinds of monoidal categories which just come with morphisms from $A \otimes B$ to $B$ (so we can only delete on the left).

Are there well studied monoidal categories like this. I had thought about left-rigid monoidal categories where the monoidal unit is the initial object, but they seem too structured.

Any connections with well studied structures would be welcome. I'm also interested in the case where the "delete on the left morphism" can be inverted.

Comment: If you can invert "delete on the left" doesn't it mean that for every $A,B$, $A\otimes B$ is isomorphic to $B$? And if this happens naturally, I don't think you obtain something nontrivial...

Comment: Also, if $\theta_A : A\otimes -\Rightarrow 1_{\mathcal C}$ is a family of natural transformations for every $A$, this induces a unique morphism $colim(A\otimes-)\to 1_{\mathcal C}$, so a morphism $(colim_A A)\otimes B\to B$ for every $B$, naturally in $B$; now $colim_A A$ is the terminal object $!$, so you have a morphism $!\otimes B\to B$ natural in $B$...

Comment: Yea, maybe asking for invertibility was too much :-). Do any structures come to mind if you disregard the invertibility request ?

Comment: I would try to measure how far you are, assuming the existence of "projections", from having a semicartesian monoidal structure: the maps in my previous comment are the components for a candidate unitor...

Comment: Apologies, as this is not relevant. But @RichardSouthwell you mentioned something in a recent youtube video that intrigued me. How is category theory used to profitably study fractal geometry?

Comment: The paper A general theory of self-similarity, Tom Leinster